# Scrapy extracting specific data

Tags: scrapy

I have an issue extracting a specific set of data using scrapy.

Here is an example code I am trying to extract.

```
<div class="Person">
      <span>Name:</span>
     Jason
     <span>Last Name:</span>
     Terry
</div
```

I want to extract just 'Terry'.

I know how to get to 'Terry' by searching in the div class through index, but the problem is that the index number is hard-coded and when you got to the next page the other person's 'Last Name' might not be in the same index.

So instead of trying to search through index I was trying to search for the span that contains 'Last Name' but every time I do that I get a return of the whole thing.

Meaning I get

Jason
Terry

But I want just 'Terry'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this xpath? `//span[contains(.,'Last Name')]/following-sibling::text()` It should return the text after span element that contains `Last Name` text

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

html_text = """<div class="Person">\n      <span>Name:</span>\n     Jason\n     <span>Last Name:</span>\n     Terry\n</div>"""

Selector(text=html_text).xpath("//span[contains(.,'Last Name')]/following-sibling::text()").get()
```

result:

```
u'\n     Terry\n'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the expression I was looking for.

Comment: No problem! Please accept the best answer if you are satisfied so this is resolved. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

can you show your code
and also try this xpath:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="Person"]/text()').extract()[2]
```

Comment: I can share and which code will you need?

Also I have tried that command and it will return Jason.

Comment: @Jackesio i am really sorry i did not see it first it is not in span i rewrite the xpath its work try it

Comment: thanks for the reply but as I mentioned I know how to get it to it via index.  And what I want is mostly how to get to it by searching 'Last Name' in the span because lets say that the next page the Last Name I am trying to get is not at the index [2].